# VBA Asynchronous data call with HTTP

Tags: vba, excel

I have made this handy VBA function that returns the HTTP status of a given URL using a **MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP** object. This function is executed synchronously and the rest of my code freezes until the request is resolved. How do turn this into an asynch call?

**Current working function:**

```
Function page_http_status(url) As String

            Dim XMLHTTP As Object

            Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
            XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
            XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"

            XMLHTTP.send
            page_http_status = XMLHTTP.Status

End Function
```

**Onreadystatechange attempt**

I know there is a *XMLHTTP.onreadystatechange* event that can trigger a named callback function, but how can I trigger this function to return the value for *page_http_status()*?

```
XMLHTTP.onreadystatechange = FunctionReadyStateChange
```

and then

```
Function FunctionReadyStateChange ()

MsgBox ("Request received! " & XMLHTTP.Status)

End Function
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757849(v=vs.85).aspx - pay attention to the 3rd parameter.

Comment: And if the request is processed asynchronously the function *can't* return a string based on the response because the request is not completed.

Comment: Your `XMLHTTP` is going to go out of scope before the event would fire anyway. You should define `XMLHTTP` outside of the function, perhaps as `Public` in the module - or somewhere else.

Comment: @user2864740 I've had a previous look at the onreadystatechange method, but this forces me to call a separate "pseudo" callback, hence jump out of the function, and loose the scope.

Comment: @Yann That's the core problem: code that must be treated async must be treated async. Otherwise it is synchronous (and blocking).

Comment: You can't stay in the original function *and* run it asynch...   There has to be a separate handler.  VBA doesn't have function pointers, so you'll need to create a wrapper class for this.

Answer (score 0):

After further reading I realised that VBA simply does not support callback functions out of the box.

Using XMLHTTP.onreadystatechange is a viable solution but it would require to work around 2 limitations:

1) XMLHTTP would have to be declared publicly in order to keep the object's scope available for the "callback" (this is fine).

2) the original function could not return a value so I would have to save the output in a procedure (instead of a "scalar" function that returns the output).